# Math.Net Numerics, normal distributions vs EXCEL functions

Tags: normal-distribution, numerics

I am planning to use Math.NET Numerics library when porting functionality from EXCEL sheet calculator to a c# program.  in Excel there is excessive use of the function **NORM.S.DIST(Z;bCummelative)**  where z is the number of standard dev from mean.  I can not clearly see from the documentation if there is a corresponding implementation of this function. Any one knows how to implement this in Math.NET Numerics?

Thank you in advance for your suggestions

Thor

Answer (score 0):

Just looking into documentation

```
float mean   = 0.7;
float stddev = 1.3;

n = new Normal(mean, stddev);

if (bCummelative) // return CDF
    return n.CumulativeDistribution(z*stddev);
else              // return PDF
    return n.Density(z*stddev);
```